# Cordova app fails to make ajax calls while running on android device

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, visual-studio-2015, content-security-policy

```
< meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *.xyz.com data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com *.xyz.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;connect-src *">
```

Please check the above Error message that I am getting in visual studio 2015 when running in device is : FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE XYZ.COM but the app works fine on ripple browser.

is the issue related to csp? if so how may I fix it?

Comment: post your config.XML file

Comment: Do you have cordova-whitelist-plugin installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the meta tag you posted. The Ajax call has been enabled in CSP (through directive "connect-src *").

Please first check if XYZ.COM is valid. And try adding the http/https schema to the meta tag directive if you are loading resource from a remote host. ex:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://*.xyz.com ";...>
```

If none of the above works, If you are having cordova-plugin-whitelist, I would suggest you adding the following codes to config.xml under root element:

```
<access origin="http://*.XYZ.com" />
<allow-intent href="http://*.XYZ.com" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*.XYZ.com"/>
```

If still nothing works, Could you share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?